# macOS Big Sur VMWare Horizon Client 8.1 laggy mouse

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware, lag, macos-big-sur

Has anyone dealt with an issue in VMWare Horizon on macOS Big Sur where the mouse is horrendously laggy? The lag is most noticeable when hovering over areas with text-input. This can be in my code editor, in a web browser search bar, sticky note, etc. Any and all text-input areas lag ridiculously. The mouse slows to a near stop and takes sometimes over a minute to drag across the screen. My mouse has different DPI toggles and I tried seeing if adjusting the DPI fixes it, and in some instances it made it worse. Using the trackpad on my laptop yields the same results so I don't believe its my mouse.

I researched the issue and people had similar problems, suggestions included enabling "Relative Mouse", toggling "Display Scaling" and "Use Full Resolution for Retina Display". None of them seem to be doing much of anything to remedy the lag. Anyone have suggestions on what to do? Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the same symptoms. I didn't realize the lag was only over editable things, so thanks for that insight. It lags when over editors in VSCode so this is pretty much unusable. Did you ever find a solution?